# Do Kleene star and complement commute?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

I am having hard time solving the following problem.

> Are there any languages for which
>   $$
> \overline{L^*} = (\overline{L})^*
> $$

Assuming $\emptyset^* = \emptyset$, if I consider $\Sigma = \{a\}$ and L = $\Sigma^*$, I get that $L^* = L$ and that $\overline{L^*} = \emptyset$. For the right side I get $\overline{L} = \emptyset$ and $(\overline{L})^* = \emptyset$. Thus, both sides are equal.

Is it true that $\emptyset^* = \emptyset$?

Comment: No, $\emptyset^* = \{\varepsilon\}$, since you can make the empty word by concatenating zero or more strings from $\emptyset$ (specifically, by concatenating zero of them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The star of a language always contains the empty string. The complement of a language containing the empty string never does. With that in mind, look at the left and the right hand sides of your proposed equality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I can think of an example in which both sides are $\emptyset$, and another one in which both are $\Sigma^*$.

(This hint works only if you allow $\emptyset^* = \emptyset$. That's the case if you define $L^* = \bigcup_{x \in L} x^*$. The usual definition is $L^* = \sum_{n \geq 0} L^n$.)

Comment: $\varepsilon\in L^*$ for any language $L$ so neither of these two claims is possible.